# Getting a NaN on click event

Tags: javascript

I have a script that simply adds fields 2 & 3, but because I have formatted the numbers as currency (`$x,xxx.xx`) field1 returns `NaN`.  Is it is possible to strip the `$` symbol from the number before doing the calculation?  I assume the comma and period won't cause the same issue.

```
onclick="document.getElementById('field1').value = (Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('field2').value,2)*100))/100 + Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('field3').value,2)*100))/100).toFixed(2);"
```

prior to clicking the calculate button, I am formatting the numbers being added `onblur="forA();"` (as soon as user leaves fields) with:

```
function forA() { 
    document.getElementById('fieldY').value = "$" + addCommas1(document.getElementById('fieldZ').value); 
} 

function addCommas1(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Comment: *I assume the comma and period won't cause the same issue.* They do: `+"1,234.50" -> NaN`

Comment: tl;dr: variable contains a string `"$123,456.78"`; how do I get a number `123456.78` from it?

Comment: Why not simply _not add them in the first place_.

Comment: your assumption that the comma not causing an issue is incorrect - parseFloat("100,340.00") gives 100.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove all non dot / digits before doing calculations

```
var currency = "$2,358.88";
var number = Number(currency.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,""));
```

Comment: `.` does not have to be escaped in a character class.

Comment: Good catch Felix ... removed it.

Comment: so my literal changes would be...var currency1 = 'field2";
var number = Number(currency1.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,"")); var currency2 = 'field2";
var number = Number(currency2.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,""));   Where do I put this code?  In the "onclick" event or in the main JScript section.  Thanks for help guys.

Comment: so what I think and what is right are different - still getting a NaN...i am trying....                                                                    var number = Number(currency.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,""));

onclick="document.getElementById('actualshoppercost').value = 
(Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('urbackyardcommission').value,2)*100))/100 + 
Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('merchantearning').value,2)*100))/100).toFixed(2);"